# Make plotlyOutput dimension reactive

Tags: r, matrix, shiny, plotly

I am plotting a matrix using heatmaply and plotly
I want to make the plotylOutput height and width reactive to the size of the matrix

If I use a reactive value in the plotlyOutput width argument I get the following error:
Error in htmltools::validateCssUnit: CSS units must be a single-element numeric or character vector

See below for a minimum version of my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(heatmaply)
library(plotly)

ui <- tags$div(id = "placeholderimage", uiOutput("plotlyimage"))



server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

 matsample <- reactive({cbind(c("A","A","A","T"),c("A","A","A","T"),c("A","A","A","G"))})

    ranges <- reactiveValues(width_im = NULL,height_im=NULL)
    ranges$width_im <- reactive(ncol(matsample())*20)

 ms <- reactive({

        alph <- c("A"=1, "C"=2, "G"=3, "T"=4, "-"=5, "N"=6, "S"=7)
        ms <- matrix(alph[matsample()], ncol = ncol(matsample()), byrow=FALSE))
        rownames(ms) <- rownames(matsample())
        return(ms)
    })

    mm <- reactive({
        data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(rownames(ms()), rep, ncol(matsample()))))
    })

  output$matimage <- renderPlotly({
    heatmaply(ms(), custom_hovertext = mm(),
                  cellnote = matsample(),cellnote_size = 6,
                  cellnote_textposition = "middle center",
                  fontsize_col = 6,grid_gap = 1,grid_size = 0.01,
                  show_dendrogram = c(FALSE, FALSE),
                  Rowv=NULL, Colv=NULL, color=rainbow(7),
                  hide_colorbar=FALSE, plot_method = "plotly")
  })

 output$plotlyimage <- renderUI(
        tags$div(class="superbigimage",
                 plotlyOutput("testplot", **width = isolate(ranges$width_im)**)
    )

})
```

This code currently throws the error because of width = isolate(ranges$width_im), how can I make the width reactive to size of matrix? 
Note my real work has matrices with over 600 columns

Comment: `ranges$width_im` in your code is a reactive value, so you should do `ranges$width_im()`, with parentheses. However you put a `reactiveVal` inside a `reactiveValues`, I'm not sure this works (I have not tried).

Comment: you were correct!! I feel a bit stupid now!. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot brackets and did not need to use isolate

```
output$plotlyimage <- renderUI(
        tags$div(class="superbigimage",
                 plotlyOutput("testplot", width = ranges$width_im())
    )
```